# How to upload products to opportunity using simple_salesforce

Tags: simple-salesforce

OK, I can be more specific now.

Tried now to simply create new opportunity line items, however, I get this error message:

esponse content: [{'message': "Error: You can't select products until you've chosen a price book for this opportunity on the products related list.", 'errorCode': 'REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING', 'fields': []}]
Code:

```
new_opportunity_line_item = SFType('OpportunityLineItem', session_id, instance)

data = {
#'PricebookEntryId': '01s0Y0000032iVBQAY',
'UnitPrice': 310.32,
'OpportunityId' : '0061v00000urNkyAAE', 
'Quantity' : '20',        
'Product2Id' : '01t1v00000I8xtyAAB'  , 
'Customer_PO__c' : '7113447008' 
}

response = new_opportunity_line_item.create(data)
```

I started yesterday with simple_salesforce, now I wanted to upload a dataframe that includes 30 products to a new opportunity that I created.

Any examples or links for reading?

I know, this is probably quite simple, but I did not find the right sources.

Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, to spam you here. After trying several options, I found the solution by myself...

When creating the opportunity, you need to assign a price book.

```
'Pricebook2Id' : '01s0Y0000032iVBQAY'
```

This price book needs to be assigned to the opportunity, not the opportunityLineItem. I got the error message when creating the opportunityLineItem.

Anyway, Thanks for your support / people who tried to help!